# Maximum function nesting level , what it means?

Tags: magento-1.9, error

when i add

```
    Mage::log($name, null, 'events.log', true);
```

in the function of dispatchEvent()

```
public static function dispatchEvent($name, array $data = array())
{
    Mage::log($name, null, 'events.log', true);
    Varien_Profiler::start('DISPATCH EVENT:'.$name);
    $result = self::app()->dispatchEvent($name, $data);
    Varien_Profiler::stop('DISPATCH EVENT:'.$name);
    return $result;
}
```

the  following error i got

> ( ! ) Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached,
>   aborting! in
>   E:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Abstract.php on line
>   119

how to avoid this?

Answer (score 2):

You can add following line in your .htacess(located at root of magento) to avoid above error. It about maximum nesting allowed for recursion by xdebug module.

```
php_value xdebug.max_nesting_level 500
```

Another solution is to add

```
 xdebug.max_nesting_level = 500
```

in your php.ini

Answer (score 0):

If you have xdebug installed then try to increase xdebug.max_nesting_level in your xedug config file or your php.ini 
http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#max_nesting_level

Also if you have installed xdebug on the production server, please remove it, as xdebug degrades the performance.
http://docs.gantry.org/gantry5/troubleshooting/max-nesting-level